# How can you add multiple conditions to a path expression?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I know that this is for one condition:

```
/bookstore/book[@price>20]
```

And that you cand use a second set of [] to specify position:

```
/bookstore/book[@price>20][1]
```

But how do you specify multiple conditions on the nodes attributes?

Comment: Be wary though. The expression `/bookstore/book[@price>20][1]` is not the same as the expression `/bookstore/book[@price>20 and postition() = 1]`. The former finds books with a price > 20, and returns the first one it finds. The latter will only return a book if it has a price > 20 and is the first book element under bookstore.

Comment: Well I had to verify myself, but @TimC is right from what I see with something like `<bookstore>
<book id="1" price="10">Book 1</book>
<book id="2" price="30">Book 2</book>
</bookstore>`. `/bookstore/book[@price>20 and position() = 1]` returns an empty node-set, `/bookstore/book[@price>20][1]` returns `<book id="2" price="30">Book 2</book>` (tested on http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and using `lxml.etree.xpath()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way, like

```
/bookstore/book[@price>20][1][@title!='']
```

You can also use `and` and `or` operator like

```
/bookstore/book[@price>20 and position() = 1 and @title!='']
```

Comment: See @TimC comment above in the question, be careful with positional conditions